# How can I create custom syntax highlighting in Markdown cells?

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

I would like to include custom syntax highlighting in Markdown cells within a Jupyter notebook similar to custom listings environments in LaTeX, such as recognizing comment delimiters, keywords, and delimiters for other highlighting. The use case I have in mind is syntax highlighting for excerpts of parameter files that I have a well defined structure without manually formatting each one. Is this possible?